# Frequently Internet Disconnects

Tags: networking, ssh, rhel, internet

I have installed **RHEL 5.8** on IMB server. Also I  have configured static IP through `eth0`. When I try to ping any website `e.g. google.com, yahoo.com` It works only for 25-40 seconds and internet connectivity get stopped. Also I have open ssh on my server due to internet disconnection ssh session geting disconnected.

But its working fine on windows. Also I have tried to internet as automatic but same issue is occurring.

Is there any issue in Server or RHEL installation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow down your problem.

1. check dmesg to see if there's something obviously wrong.
2. Does the internet connection come back up? if not, how do you get it back up?
3. Are you using dhcp or static ip? is it configured on /etc/network/interfaces ? if so, post your config

Comment: Internet connection come backup automatically. I am using static ip address. When I am trying to connect my server through ssh it get connect but after 20-30 seconds its get disconnected and an error message occurs `The semaphore timeout period has expired.`